# Fix Windows Boot Problems tool in Macrium Rescue Media looks for Active Partition even in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, macrium, rescue-disk

I have a GPT disk with a Windows install, and I have a multiboot BIOS/UEFI Rescue Media disk that I boot in UEFI mode (and I get “[UEFI]” in the title bar), but when I select Fix Windows Boot Problems and choose the Windows install on the GPT disk, the next screen I get is looking for an Active Partition (the MBR/BIOS version of the wizard), not a Boot Drive (the GPT/UEFI version of the wizard). My understanding is that booting the Rescue Media in UEFI should cause me to see the UEFI version of the wizard, but I am not seeing that.

Rescue Media created with Macrium Reflect Free v8.0.6584.

Comment: In UEFI mode Windows depends on the boot flag to be in the ESP.

Comment: @ChanganAuto This question isn’t about booting Windows in UEFI; I already know the Windows install has issues with its UEFI boot (and they’re more than just a flag, I’m reasonably sure). That’s why I’m trying to use Macrium’s Fix Windows Boot Problems, because it’s advertised as fixing these issues. This question is about that Fix Windows Boot Problems, which isn’t working the way the docs indicate (as far as I understand).

Comment: Depending on the "damage" it may not be possible to fix. And in any case AFAIK Macrium Reflect does nothing more than the native Windows tools that you can run from Windows installation media.

Comment: And, by the way, this https://superuser.com/questions/1756051/copy-win10-partitions-plus-a-partition-from-another-disk-onto-new-drive can't possibly work.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Well, if you want to answer that question, backing up your assertion that it can’t work, I’d accept that. As for this question, even if the Rescue Media doesn’t do what I want it to, I’d still like to know why it’s not even giving me the correct options/wizard.

Comment: I recommend you try booting Windows media instead. There's a chance it'll detect the "Frankenstein" installation and be able to "repair" it - reinstall a correct bootloader - or, if not possible it may work if you select to reinstall Windows but keeping personal data. Your best bet if with the official installation procedure, not with 3rd party tools.